# Need to get remapped values of table using Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have two tables.

1. In first table I have some keys in Column "Key"
2. In Second table, I have some mapping data, where for the key i have mapped some values.

Now, if I import two tables, and I select Key in first table and value in Second table, I will get mapped values of the corresponding key.
But if the key is not present in the mapping data table, the key is not showing in the Output.

**I need to get the key as value in Output.**

Example:

```
Table 1
------------
Key
A
B
C
D

Table 2
--------------
Key Value
A     A1
B     B1
C     B2

Output
-----------
Key Value
A     A1
B     B1
C     B2

Expected Output
--------------
Key   Value
A      A1
B      B1
C      B2
D      D
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this problem. I will show you how i did it using DAX.

The first thing you need to do is create a relationship between both tables:
[image]

Then go to Table 1 and create the following column using DAX:

```
Value = 
VAR __value = CALCULATE( DISTINCT( 'Table 2'[Value] ), RELATEDTABLE( 'Table 2' ) )
Return 
    IF(
        ISBLANK( __value ),
        'Table 1'[Key],
        __value
    )
```

This will create the expected result:

[image]

This will only work if you have only one value for every key.

Comment: Thanks! @agustin-palacios . But my tables are related as bi directional. If I change it to Single, It throws error as invalid relationship. Also, I have looked on LOOKUPVALUE [DAX] function, but the syntax allows us to search with single value. Please let me know if you have any other solutions to this. Thanks in advance!!